XeLateX stopped compiling
I am using xelatex on vscode and i was working on a lab report when i set up some simple figures and now it doesnt generate the pdf anymore and no problems are detected. It worked perfectly before introducing the figure so i thought that was the problem but even after deleting those lines it still does not work. Im still a complete rookie so I have no clue on whats wrong. I got the following message:
dvipdfmx:fatal: Unable to open "laboratorio.pdf".
No output PDF file written.
Sorry, but xelatex did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
2024-04-27 22:38:04,005-0400 FATAL xelatex.core - Invalid argument
2024-04-27 22:38:04,005-0400 FATAL xelatex.core - Function: fwrite
2024-04-27 22:38:04,005-0400 FATAL xelatex.core - Result: 22
2024-04-27 22:38:04,005-0400 FATAL xelatex.core - Data: 
2024-04-27 22:38:04,006-0400 FATAL xelatex.core - Source:
Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h:531
2024-04-27 22:38:04,006-0400 FATAL xelatex - Invalid argument
2024-04-27 22:38:04,006-0400 FATAL xelatex - Info:
2024-04-27 22:38:04,006-0400 FATAL xelatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\include\miktex/C4P/C4P.h
2024-04-27 22:38:04,006-0400 FATAL xelatex - Line: 531

you get that message from dvipdfmx if something is blocking the pdf, e.g. if it has been opened in adobe reader. So close everything (including some preview in the explorer) and try again.

I have now sorted the issue, although Im still not sure what the problem was exactly, but closing the previews did not solve the issue. I think it had something to do with the size of the images I was trying to include. Thanks for the tip, next time I see that message I will try to relate it to a pdf issue
